# Halmos counterexamples not the actual counterexamples

Tags: symbolic-execution, halmos

I have the following test:

```js
    function check_strippedSqrt(uint256 randomNumber) public pure {
        assert(_solmateSqrtStripped(randomNumber) == _mathMastersSqrtStripped(randomNumber));
    }
```

Running `// halmos --function check_strippedSqrt --solver-timeout-assertion 0`, I get the following output:

```
Counterexample: 
    p_randomNumber_uint256 = 0x00c0030200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (339255395596383497272635013744257360154495608801324196200158840428074893312)
Counterexample: 
    p_randomNumber_uint256 = 0x0000000000c23ba3000000000000000000504291000c000046d4c68d1e0f0000 (79902803542272641499737486351572344810652023047597925213322280960)
Counterexample: 
    p_randomNumber_uint256 = 0x000000000000000000c400590000000000000000000000000000885100000004 (18773200449252860965249471210541399248518453506219180036)
Counterexample: 
    p_randomNumber_uint256 = 0x00000000000000000000000000cc048100000000000000000000000000000000 (4549744366069306962921659798542634575967813632)
Counterexample: 
    p_randomNumber_uint256 = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000ab000103821701a4000004838a9701 (887882843123342069450284981883148033)
Counterexample: 
    p_randomNumber_uint256 = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000009fa800133200004d200000 (193012564271016176024289280)
Counterexample: 
    p_randomNumber_uint256 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000efd19acd649800 (67502982234937344)
Counterexample: 
    p_randomNumber_uint256 = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000099999c (10066332)
```

Which is great! I expect any of these will be the correct counterexample. However, trying one of the counter-examples PASSES for me as a foundry test (it should fail right?):

```js
    function test_strippedSqrt() public pure {
        uint256 randomNumber = 10066332; // one of the outputs from above
        assert(_solmateSqrtStripped(randomNumber) == _mathMastersSqrtStripped(randomNumber));
    }
```

`forge test --mt test_strippedSqrt`.

What's going on? Am I looking at counter examples wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Halmos finds list a single counterexample for each path it finds an issue, it doesn't list every possible counterexample (this could potentially be a *lot* of counterexamples.

So if you're looking to use a counterexample on another test, just know it's one of many possibilities.

Additionally, the validity test was wrong.